# How to check if a remote REST service is up using Spring?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have a small REST application built using SpringBoot. I use a Feign Client to make requests to a similar application.

What I am trying to figure out is how to check if the application that the feign is making requests to is up. There is a path (api/online) that returns a 200 OK if the server is up.
What I tried to do is make a GET request that returns a ResponseEntity and check its status code. But when the server is down I don't get any response and instead an Exception is thrown.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: `when the server is down I don't get any response and instead an Exception is thrown.` Please, post your related code.

Answer (score 1):

I think, to handle Exceptions gracefully you may use circutebreaker with fallback.
Take a look at [this article](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#spring-cloud-feign-hystrix-fallback)

Actuator is not a option, because if app goes down, actuator would not work as well.

Also take a look at discovery service like Eurika - so before requesting something, you feign client would check if service is up and running through discovery service

Answer (score 0):

Generally actuators are used to check the health of the springboot apps - http://localhost:8080/actuator/health. You can refer this site on how to implement them https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-actuator/.

Answer (score 0):

So I will leave here my own solution, even though it feels a little bit primitive. What I did, in the end, was a simple try and catch where I checked that the request isn't throwing an exception, if it did I returned false, else, I returned true.
I wasn't able to solve it another way, feel free to come with other options.